# Are schools required to disclose accurate results of random drug searches?

Tags: united-states, education, michigan, foia

I go to a school which has a serious problem with underage vape usage. The police sometimes conducts random drug searches, and after every search, parents are informed via email. Each email has consistently said that the search did not find any illegal substances.

Are public school required to disclose accurate information about the drug searches? Can they lie about the results to make themselves seem better?

Comment: That's a little weird. AFAIK, there is technically no law against minors possessing tobacco. It is illegal to sell tobacco to minors, so a minor possessing tobacco would be evidence of a crime, but not a crime itself.

Comment: I think that may be the answer. Nicotine is not an illegal substance, and either none of the children are on illegal drugs or the police lab did not test for the relevant substances.

Comment: @Acccumulation I edited the question to clarify the use of vape with nicotine.

Comment: @Acccumulation Michigan law 722.642 says it is illegal for a minor to possess a tobacco product.

Comment: I know it is. That's not my question though.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any law requiring schools to proactively disclose the results of these sweeps, but if you asked for them, the [Michigan Freedom of Information Act](https://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(rr305qjzawcprdo5iutyltlq))/mileg.aspx?page=getobject&objectname=mcl-15-233) would likely require both the police and the school to release records that would give you an accurate picture of what happened.

At the very least, I would expect the police department to write up the results of its sweeps in a report to send up the chain of command. I would also expect that those results would be communicated in writing to the school district. The police should also maintain a log of all property they have seized; if they seized anything from the school, it should show up there, as well.